# Phalcon Middlewares

Tags: php, phalcon, middleware

Есть ли в Phalcon понятие Middleware, сходное с таковым в Laravel? Некая прослойка между роутером и контроллером, через которую проходит запрос. Ну, в качестве примера самое простое - Auth. Middleware, в которой будет определяться, автризован ли пользователь, если да - там, `return next();` например, если нет - то вернём статус 403, допустим. Ну или какой-то аналогичный механизм в Phalcon вообще предусмотрен? Нашёл в документации [вот это](https://docs.phalconphp.com/ru/3.2/application-micro), но это, скажем так, не совсем то, что мне нужно.

Comment: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.2/application-micro#events https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.2/application-micro#middleware

Comment: @E_p это микро же. Мне не микро надо. Да и не на уровне функций. А если я хочу более сложную логику? А если я хочу к контролллерам обращаться?

Comment: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.2/application#events ?

Comment: @E_p ивенты это какбэ не совсем мидлварь. А вернее даже совсем не...

Comment: Event можетт служить хуком для Middleware.

Comment: @E_p как? Что в этом случае будет выступать в качестве Middleware? Мне примерчик бы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И все же, ничего кроме плагинов в phalcon еще не придумали. То, о чем вы говорите, реализуется именно при помощи ивентов и плагинов:

```
$eventsManager = new \Phalcon\Events\Manager();
$dispatcher = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher();
$dispatcher->setEventsManager($eventsManager);
$eventsManager->attach('dispatch:beforeDispatchLoop', new \Mycompany\Frontend\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin());
```

и сам класс плагина:

```
class AuthenticationPlugin extends \Phalcon\Mvc\User\Plugin 
{
    public function beforeDispatchLoop(Event $event, Dispatcher $dispatcher)
    {
    // code
    }
}
```